# Problema en javascript con conversión de divisas

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hola amigos soy nuevo en js y estoy tratando de hacer un ejercicio sobre compra y venta de dinero, dólar, euro, centenario y peso. Mi problema es que no sé como hacer para que si escoge compra y el tipo de dinero lo multiplique por la cantidad y si escoge venta y el tipo de dinero vmultiplicar por cantidad pero diferente precio para compra y venta.

```js
function calcular()
{
var  de = document.getElementById("de").value;
var  f = document.getElementById("f").value;
var monto = document.getElementById("monto").value;
  var dolar=20.01
  var centenario=45.000
  var euro=22.24
    resultado=0;


  if(de==1&&f==a)
  {
      resultado=monto*dolar;
  }

  if  (de==1&&f==b)
  {
      resultado=monto*euro;
  }

 if(de==1&&f==c)
{
  resultado=monto*centenario; 
}



if(de==2&&f==b)
{
  resultado=monto*euro; 
}

else(de==2&&f==b)
{
  resultado=monto*euro; 
}
  document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML="Resultado: $"+resultado.toFixed(2);
}
```

```html
  <form class="form">
            <h2>Rellenar</h2>
            <p type="Acción:"><select id="de">
                <option value="" id="1">Compra</option>
                <option value="" id="2">Venta</option>
            </select></p>

            <p type="Moneda:"><select id="f">
                <option value="" id="a">Dolar</option>
                <option value="" id="b">Euro</option>
                <option value="" id="c">Centenario</option>
                <option value="" id="d">Pesos</option>
            </select></p>
            <p type="Monto:"><input type="number" id="monto" name="monto" ></input></p>
            <button onclick="calcular()">Calcular</button> <br>
            <h6 id="resultado">resultado:$0.00 </h6>
          </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

EL precio de compra y venta son diferentes, en tu caso usas solo una variable con valor fijo `var dolar=20.01` Creo que deberías usar un valor distinto para cada caso `var compraDolar=20.01` `var ventaDolar=20.51` (no se cual será el valor de la moneda, solo es un ejemplo)

Comment: Si gracias pero lo que me interesa más es donde hare las operaciones, porque no me jala si pongo puto if. Así como esta en el ejemplo que di.

Answer (score 0):

El problema está aquí:  `value=""`, en vez de ponerlo en el id tienes que ponerlo así `value="1"` para que puedas obtener la opción seleccionada.
Pequeño ejemplo funcional (el resto puedes deducirlo):

```js
function calcular()
{
var  de = document.getElementById("de").value;
var  f = document.getElementById("f").value;
var monto = document.getElementById("monto").value;
  var dolar=20.01
  var centenario=45.000
  var euro=22.24
  var resultado=0;


  if(de==1 && f=="a")
  {
      resultado=monto*dolar;
  }



  document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML="Resultado: $"+resultado.toFixed(2);
}
```

```html
<h2>Rellenar</h2>
            <p type="Acción:"><select id="de">
                <option value="1" >Compra</option>
                <option value="2" >Venta</option>
            </select></p>

            <p type="Moneda:"><select id="f">
                <option value="a" >Dolar</option>
                <option value="b" >Euro</option>
                <option value="c" >Centenario</option>
                <option value="d" >Pesos</option>
            </select></p>
            <p type="Monto:"><input type="number" id="monto" name="monto" ></input></p>
            <button onclick="calcular()">Calcular</button> <br>
            <h6 id="resultado">resultado:$0.00 </h6>
```

*Nota cuando pones `value="a"` (es string) en la condición del  if debes ponerlo entre comillas `f=="a"` sino da error.

Por ultimo el 'else' no lleva condicional entre parentesis, solo se ejecuta cuando su if anterior no se ejecuta.

Te dejo algo mas de información al respecto:

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else